# Issue with Failures in Chapter 7 of Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby, testing, encryption, rspec

When I run bundle exec rspec spec/ I'm getting 21 examples and 3 failures. Those failures being:

Failures:

1) User has_password? method should be true if the passwords match
     Failure/Error: @user.has_password?(@attr[:password]).should be_true
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in`block (3 levels) in '

2) User has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
     Failure/Error: @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:51:in`block (3 levels) in '

3) User password validations should accept valid email addresses
     Failure/Error: it "should reject invalid email addresses" do
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_3:0x00000102eb38b0>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97:in`block (3 levels) in '

I'll post my user_spec.rb file bc I think it's almost right, but not completely. Note the commented out ends, I had those in play before but thought they were wrong so commented them out.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      :name => "Example User", 
      :email => "user@example.com", 
      :password => "foobar", 
      :password_confirmation => "foobar" }
  end

    it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end

  describe "password encryption" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = User.create!(@attr)
  end

    it "should have an encrypted password attribute" do
       @user.should respond_to(:encrypted_password)
  end

    it "should set the encrypted password" do
      @user.encrypted_password.should_not be_blank
  end
end

  describe "has_password? method" do

    it "should be true if the passwords match" do
      @user.has_password?(@attr[:password]).should be_true
  end

    it "should be false if the passwords don't match" do
      @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
  end
end

  describe "password validations" do

  it "should require a password" do
    User.new(@attr.merge(:password => "", :password_confirmation => "")).
      should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require a matching password confirmation" do
    User.new(@attr.merge(:password_confirmation => "invalid")).
      should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject short passwords" do
    short = "a" * 5
    hash = @attr.merge(:password => short, :password_confirmation => short)
    User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject long passwords" do
    short = "a" * 5
    hash = @attr.merge(:password => short, :password_confirmation => short)
    User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require a name" do
     no_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
     no_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require an email address" do
    no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
    no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should accept valid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo.com THE_USER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp]
    addresses.each do |address|
      valid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
      valid_email_user.should be_valid
    end
  #end

  it "should reject invalid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
    addresses.each do |address|
      invalid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
      invalid_email_user.should_not be_valid
   end
  #end

  it "should reject duplicate email addresses" do
    # Put a user with given email address into the database.
    User.create!(@attr)
   user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
    user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
    end

  it "should reject email addresses identical up to case" do
       upcased_email = @attr[:email].upcase
       User.create!(@attr.merge(:email => upcased_email))
       user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
       user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
    end

  it "should reject names that are too long" do
    long_name = "a" * 51
    long_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => long_name))
    long_name_user.should_not be_valid
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My user.rb file is fine I think.

So the 3 failures thing is one aspect of my problem, but the thing that really worries me is the following command:

bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb -e "has_password\? method"

The result in terminal is this:

No examples matched {:full_description=>/(?-mix:has_password\\?\ method)/}.

Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

According to Hartl I should have 2 examples, and 0 failures. Ideas? Any input appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

in your user_spec.rb file.

make sure you have:

```
       before(:each) do
         @user = User.create!(@attr)
       end
```

right after the following line:

```
     describe "has_password? method" do
```

it's missing from the code in the tutorial. you'll see it's part of the password encryption block. it looks like it stubs out a user for that test. it's not very DRY...probably a way to have that stub block run for each describe block, but that's a bit further along than i am. :) hope it helps...got my tests working.